# Download .sql file BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to download my query from Google BigQuery as .sql file?

I can only save queries but I do not see anywhere the option to download it as .sql file.

Comment: What are you expecting from a ".sql" file? How should the contents look?

Comment: It's just the query itself, I could copy/paste it in an editor and change the extension - still this is prone to mistakes because there is an intermediate steps between the query I executed and the storing process.